# Le serveur a rencontré une erreur interne qui l''a empêché de satisfaire la requête

Tags: spring, jdbctemplate

I'm using JdbcTemplate in Spring for the first time;

I want to recuperate data from the DB; I don't no what's my errors ;

please help me to resolve this problem and by giving a helpful courses to understand using JdbcTemplate in spring;

here is my code:

### CoursChangeDaoImpl

```
 public List<CoursChange> listeCours(Date datJourCchn)
 {

 String sql=
 "SELECT * FROM COURS_CHANGE c   where  c.DAT_JOUR_CCHN=:DAT_JOUR_CCHN";
 
 List<CoursChange> coursChange= jdbcTemplate.query(sql,new Object[]          /*******/
 {datJourCchn},new CoursChangeMapper());
 return coursChange;

 }



 class CoursChangeMapper implements RowMapper<CoursChange>{
 @Override
 public CoursChange mapRow(ResultSet resultSet, int rwNum) throws
 SQLException {
 CoursChange coursChange =new CoursChange();
 coursChange.getDevise().getLibDevDev();
 coursChange.getDevise().getLibSiglDev();
 coursChange.getCodEtatCchn();
 coursChange.getMontCabaCchn();
 coursChange.getMontCabcCchn();

 return coursChange;
 }


 }

 class CoursRowMapper implements RowMapper{

 @Override
 public Object mapRow(ResultSet result, int rowNum) throws SQLException {

 CoursChange coursChange =new CoursChange();
 coursChange.setIdCoursChange(result.getInt("ID_COURS_CHANGE"));
 coursChange.setCodEtatCchn(result.getString("COD_ETAT_CCHN"));
 coursChange.setMontCabaCchn(result.getFloat("MONT_CABA_CCHN"));
 coursChange.setMontCabcCchn(result.getFloat("MONT_CABC_CCHN"));
 coursChange.setMontCvbaCchn(result.getFloat("MONT_CVBA_CCHN"));
 coursChange.setMontCvbcCchn(result.getFloat("MONT_CVBC_CCHN"));

 coursChange.setDatJourCchn(result.getDate("DAT_JOUR_CCHN"));
 coursChange.setTimeCchn(result.getString("TIME_CCHN"));



 return coursChange;


 }

 }
```

Comment: My error is:  Le serveur a rencontré une erreur interne qui l''a empêché de satisfaire la requête.

Comment: Keep it English please.

Comment: Translated Error equivalent: Error 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: Sorry: 

the error is so general:
The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling the request

Comment: Check the server log and post the stacktrace.

Comment: I have already answered my question with the right answer ; thank you Sir for having responded me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the solution ; it's so simple

First at all : I should put the annotation @Autowired before private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate; to be able to  use it :)

1)

```
@Autowired
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
```

Second this is the correct code to recuperate data :)

2)

```
public List<CoursChange> listeCours(Date datJourCchn) {



    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy");
    try {
        datJourCchn =sdf.parse("17042016");
    } catch (ParseException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("debut");

    String sql = "SELECT d.LIB_DEV_DEV , d.LIB_SIGL_DEV , c.DAT_JOUR_CCHN , c.COD_ETAT_CCHN , c.MONT_CABA_CCHN , c.MONT_CABC_CCHN  , c.MONT_CVBA_CCHN , c.MONT_CVBC_CCHN  ,c.TIME_CCHN ,c.ID_COURS_CHANGE   FROM COURS_CHANGE c , DEVISE d  where c.COD_DEV_DEV=d.COD_DEV_DEV and c.DAT_JOUR_CCHN=?";



         List<CoursChange> coursChanges = jdbcTemplate.query(sql,
            new Object[] { datJourCchn }, new RowMapper<CoursChange>() {

             @Override
                public CoursChange mapRow(ResultSet result, int rowNum)
                        throws SQLException {

                    System.out.println("debut Mapper 22222");

                    CoursChange coursChange = new CoursChange();
                    Devise devise = new Devise();
                    coursChange.setIdCoursChange(result
                            .getInt("ID_COURS_CHANGE"));
                    coursChange.setCodEtatCchn(result
                            .getString("COD_ETAT_CCHN"));
                    coursChange.setMontCabaCchn(result
                            .getFloat("MONT_CABA_CCHN"));
                    coursChange.setMontCabcCchn(result
                            .getFloat("MONT_CABC_CCHN"));
                    coursChange.setMontCvbaCchn(result
                            .getFloat("MONT_CVBA_CCHN"));
                    coursChange.setMontCvbcCchn(result
                            .getFloat("MONT_CVBC_CCHN"));
                    coursChange.setDatJourCchn(result
                            .getDate("DAT_JOUR_CCHN"));
                    coursChange.setTimeCchn(result.getString("TIME_CCHN"));
                    devise.setLibDevDev(result.getString("LIB_DEV_DEV"));
                    devise.setLibSiglDev(result.getString("LIB_SIGL_DEV"));
                    coursChange.setDevise(devise);
                    System.out.println("Fin Mapper");
                    System.out.println("coursChange jdbcTemplate" + coursChange);
                    return coursChange;
                }
            });
    System.out.println("Fin");
    return coursChanges;

}
```